# Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I've been through 30++ topics already and couldn't figure what mistake I made. Maybe somebody that is not me could see what I did wrong that i got: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. Just to make sure, I'm using newest files from github, but I can't get it done. The hosting is az.pl maybe anybody had to do something with it already? I deleted emails + password :)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['nick'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$visitor_tel = $_POST['tel'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');    // dodanie klasy phpmailer
require_once('class.smtp.php');    // dodanie klasy smtp
$mail = new PHPMailer();    //utworzenie nowej klasy phpmailer
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mailng.az.pl";    //adres serwera SMTP wysyłającego e-mail 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";    //do wysłania zostanie użyty serwer SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;    //włączenie autoryzacji do serwera SMTP
$mail->Username = "";    //nazwa użytkownika do skrzynki e-mail
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = "";    //Pełny adres e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Formularz kontaktowy";    //imię i nazwisko lub nazwa     użyta do wysyłania wiadomości
$mail->Password = "";    //hasło użytkownika do skrzynki e-mail
$mail->Port = 587; //port serwera SMTP 
$mail->Subject = "Nowe zlecenie: $visitor_email";    //Temat wiadomości, można stosować zmienne i znaczniki HTML
$mail->Body = "Nazwa zleceniodawcy: $name \n";
 $mail->Body .="Email kontaktowy: $visitor_email \n";
 $mail->Body .=   "Telefon kontaktowy: $visitor_tel\n";
  $mail->Body .=  "Zlecenie: $message";  //Treść wiadomości, można stosować zmienne i znaczniki HTML 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';    // 
$mail->AddAddress ("","");    //adres skrzynki e-mail oraz nazwa
                                                //adresata, do którego trafi wiadomość
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header('Location: emailsent.html');
}  
?>
```

Comment: With SMTPDebug = 1 I got:

`2016-10-23 17:36:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO lunicdesign.pl 2016-10-23 17:36:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2016-10-23 17:36:44 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 2016-10-23 17:36:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-10-23 17:36:44 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:  xutT����`���;�i�D��M�6���� 2016-10-23 17:36:44 SMTP connect() failed.``

Comment: 30+ articles and managed to miss the suggestions to base your code on the examples provided and read the troubleshooting guide linked to from the error message you saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sake of other that use az.pl here is changed script that works (without tls and with commented out $mail->isSMTP();)

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['nick'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $visitor_tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $message = $_POST['msg'];
  require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');    // dodanie klasy phpmailer
require_once('class.smtp.php');    // dodanie klasy smtp
$mail = new PHPMailer();    //utworzenie nowej klasy phpmailer
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mailng.az.pl";    //adres serwera SMTP wysyłającego e-mail 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";    //do wysłania zostanie użyty serwer SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;    //włączenie autoryzacji do serwera SMTP
$mail->Username = "";    //nazwa użytkownika do skrzynki e-mail
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = "";    //Pełny adres e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Formularz kontaktowy";    //imię i nazwisko lub nazwa użyta do wysyłania wiadomości
$mail->Password = "";    //hasło użytkownika do skrzynki e-mail
$mail->Port = 587; //port serwera SMTP 
$mail->Subject = "Nowe zlecenie: $visitor_email";    //Temat wiadomości, można stosować zmienne i znaczniki HTML
$mail->Body = "Nazwa zleceniodawcy: $name \n";
 $mail->Body .="Email kontaktowy: $visitor_email \n";
 $mail->Body .=   "Telefon kontaktowy: $visitor_tel\n";
  $mail->Body .=  "Zlecenie: $message";  //Treść wiadomości, można stosować zmienne i znaczniki HTML 
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';    // 
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;   //wyłączenie TLS
$mail->AddAddress ("","");    //adres skrzynki e-mail oraz nazwa
                                                //adresata, do którego trafi wiadomość
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header('Location: emailsent.html');
}  
?>
```

Comment: This has been suggested in other places. This "fixes" SMTP by not using SMTP. It's important to understand why code works, not just that it does.

Comment: Thank you Synchro, but I never saw empty smtpsecure anywhere (anywhere I looked) and by random I left it that way between switching between tls and ssl :P Good it works :) I'm not PHP head and never got to work on it more than I should but after this lesson - I need to :)

Comment: An empty string in SMTPSecure is undefined. If you want to disable encryption, set both `SMTPSecure = false` and `SMTPAutoTLs = false`. But if you're using an ISP that requires authentication over an unencrypted connection, it's time to find a new ISP.